# USB doesn't mount

Tags: 12.04, usb, mount, fat32, exfat

I have a problem. I have had Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop for 2 years and up until now no problems with the USB. But since this evening the pc doesn't mount the USB. I read some discussions but the problem persists.
with

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

shows

```
    Disk /dev/sdb: 2003 MB, 2003828736 bytes
43 heads, 42 sectors/track, 2167 cylinders, total 3913728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00095b2e
```

My USB  has got `fat32` filesystem:

[image]

And with a USB with `ext4` filesystem,shows:

```
    Disk /dev/sdb: 31.5 GB, 31457280000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3824 cylinders, total 61440000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000eecfd
```

[image]
So the Pc sees that the USB is connected but I don't see it in file directory.
[image]

Where data is a partition of my SSD.
whit`sudo lsusb` command:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8644:8003
```

Where the last line is the 2GB USB
I have Arduino and it works without problems. 
with the other pc in my house, with ubuntu too the USB are read perfectly. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Maybe the output of dmesg just after you try to connect the USB might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mount Helper was **disabled** (I don't know why)
[image]

Once **abilitated**, all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Mount device/partition manually.

1. Try:

   ```
   # mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1
   ```
2. If problem persists:

   ```
   # mkdir /media/$USER/USB1
   # mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media/$USER/USB1
   ```
3. You can try to mount a device/partition using UUID/LABEL of device/partition. Double-click on given device/partition in *GParted* to retrieve `<uuid>`. Then:

   ```
   # mount -t ntfs UUID=<uuid>
   ```

   or

   ```
   # mount -t ntfs /dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid>
   ```

   or

   ```
   # mount -t ntfs LABEL=<label>
   ```

   or

   ```
   # mount -t ntfs /dev/disk/by-label/<label>
   ```

   3a. You can define mountpoint:

   ```
   # mount -t ntfs /dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid> <mountpoint>
   ```
4. If none doesn't lead to supposed result, use usb ammeter to check whether usb port is powered properly.

Further reading:

A. `$ man mount`

B. *mount* on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mount).

C. *mount(8)* on [die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. With second command (with the mount point I can mount the USB, but I able to use it only with root permissions (I created a mountpoint in/media/USB_mount (where I have other mountpoint)).
But my question is: why from a day to an other my PC doesn't mount USB automatically?

Comment: I don't know why (maybe kernel problems). But I have found additional solution:
`sudo apt-get install usbmount`.

This thread on [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) might be also helpful for you.

Comment: with Disk application I see the USB and I can mount it without root access. Thanks for your help. Waiting for the answer  about why not automatically mount.